rsyslog separate log of sources of data
We have a rsyslog server running on Red Hat. Listening on UDP and TCP 514.
This simply forwards everything to a MS agent on the server which send the logs to Azure Log Analytics/Sentinel. The Azure part is managed by a 3rd party SOC.
Is there a way to log only the source IP and maybe amount of log lines for any systems sending to the syslog server? I want these on the server as that is my teams remit. We do not want to get this data from Azure.
Thanks in advance for any ideas/solutions.
Regards
Mark
